# transparent panel in activity

Tags: android

I am trying to set transparent panel using [this](http://www.androidapps.org/tag/mapview) tutorial in my app  but whenever i use following xml to my activity it comes up with force to close

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@+id/home_container" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/city_map_view" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:clickable="true"             
            android:apiKey="0DUEIIn35xtmC6Vk1JkFEF74kwkUjgb7HrUMKfA"/>

    <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingLeft="5px"
                    android:paddingTop="5px"
                    android:paddingRight="5px">

        <com.pocketjourney.view.TransparentPanel
                android:id="@+id/transparent_panel" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5px"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingBottom="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px">

            <Button android:id="@+id/button_click_me"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click Me!"/>

        </com.pocketjourney.view.TransparentPanel>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks

logcat

```
07-04 00:14:09.874: DEBUG/ddm-heap(3005): Got feature list request
07-04 00:14:09.974: DEBUG/dalvikvm(55): GC freed 315 objects / 12176 bytes in 264ms
07-04 00:14:10.004: WARN/dalvikvm(101): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
07-04 00:14:10.084: WARN/dalvikvm(3005): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/droidnova/android/howto/optionmenu/ControlMenu; (69)
07-04 00:14:10.084: WARN/dalvikvm(3005): Link of class 'Lcom/droidnova/android/howto/optionmenu/ControlMenu;' failed
07-04 00:14:10.094: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3005): Shutting down VM
07-04 00:14:10.094: WARN/dalvikvm(3005): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e390)
07-04 00:14:10.104: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu/com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu.ControlMenu}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu.ControlMenu in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@448a0d70
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu.ControlMenu in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@448a0d70
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-04 00:14:10.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3005):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2489)
```

and now i am getting this

```
07-04 00:28:31.914: ERROR/ActivityManager(101): fail to set top app changed!
```

Comment: What error did you get? Maybe the TransparentPanel isn't where your xml says it is? Or maybe you didn't implement the custom view correctly. Provide us with your error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the XML declaration

is saying in the packages com/pocketjourney/view there will a class called TransparentPanel

so I assume your package isn't that, you will have named it yourself so you need to update your XML

> com.your.package.TransparentPanel

Comment: Thanks for your concern , i have fixed this and put the TransparentPanel class also but still i am getting the force to close , i have updated it with logcat errors  , please give a look to it

Comment: and now i am only getting 07-04 00:28:31.914: ERROR/ActivityManager(101): fail to set top app changed!

Comment: I fixed your original problem. Please mark this as answered and create another question. You can't just change the question it makes answer irrelevant for other people with the same issues,