# Why is my 'transparent' overlay view opaque?

Tags: java, android, xml, overlay, transparency

I have a single activity with a simple layout (a bunch of coloured panels) and I'm trying to overlay a small moving graphic on a transparent view over the top. Like @umar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565806/transparent-panel-in-activity) I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.androidapps.org/tag/mapview) but my overlay view is refusing to be transparent. I can make the view appear, it contains just what it should, but the background of the view is black and however I try to make it transparent fails. I've tried a few of the solutions mentioned on SO and it always comes out the same.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/everything"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00ffffff"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_1_bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row_1_table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#808080"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/row_1_pantone"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/row_1_rgb"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/row_1_hex"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:paddingRight="5px" 
android:paddingTop="5px" 
android:paddingLeft="5px" 
android:gravity="bottom" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00808080"> 

<barry.pantone.TransparentPanel 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/transparent_panel" 
        android:paddingRight="5px" 
        android:paddingTop="5px" 
        android:paddingLeft="5px" 
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:background="#00808080"> 

        <Button 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/button_click_me" 
            android:text="Click Me!"
            /> 
</barry.pantone.TransparentPanel> 
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My TransparentPanel.java is straight from the tutorial, using:

```
innerPaint.setARGB(225, 75, 75, 75);
```

to make a transparent panel, and this is my onCreate from the main activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    sPantone = res.getStringArray(R.array.pantone); // gets colour definitions

    iHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    PopulateTable (); // draws colours in the various layout elements
    }
```

The problem is that whatever I do inside the view is fine - I can draw a semi transparent panel over other elements **in that view**, but the overlay view itself has a black background which obscures the layout beneath. If anyone can help me understand why transparency doesn't work, I will be eternally grateful.

Many thanks

Baz

**EDIT**

Following another idea I tried moving the definition of the overlay out into its own XML file and using a LayoutInflater to inflate and add the new view. Nope. Exactly the same - the additional view has a solid background. Here's the tranny.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:background="#80000040"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:paddingRight="5dip" 
android:paddingTop="5dip" 
android:paddingLeft="5dip" 
android:gravity="bottom" 
android:orientation="vertical"
> 
<Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button_click_me" 
    android:text="Click Me!"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the code from onCreate to inflate the new view and add it to the main layout:

```
private View view;
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.everything);
view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.tranny, parent, false);
parent.addView(view);
```

Basically I've gone about creating exactly the same result using a different technique. Handy to learn about LayoutInflater for the first time, but no help re transparency :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, no answers so I'm assuming there's no way to use `parent.addView(view)` to add an overlaid view which has a transparent background. I had hoped to add a narrow transparent view over the right hand edge of my layout (a scrollbar) into which I could draw a bitmap indicating the position in the big list of displayed items.

Instead I have now made my whole layout slightly narrower and left room for a narrow `LinearLayout` down the right edge, which has a black background, and into *that* I draw my bitmap, so I get this:

[image]

I would have preferred to put the pointer over the top of the blocks of colour, but unless some guru in the future finds this question and shows us how to do it, I'm close enough.

Baz.

Answer (score 0):

> I can draw a semi transparent panel over other elements in that view

Exactly this. You need the "transparency" to be overlaying what's behind it.

The transparency is likely working, but the parent layout's background is transparent (#00ffffff), so the background of the overlay looks black.

Change your root layout's background and you'll likely see that the transparency is working.

If you want it overlay the other elements of your view, you need the transparency as a child to that section of the layout. The way it's currently laid out is like:

```
<App>
  <Content>
  </Content>
  <Overlay>
  </Overlay>
</App>
```

Whereas you need:

```
<App>
  <Content>
    <Overlay>
    </Overlay>
  </Content>
</App>
```

If you look at the source for that tutorial you're following, you'll see the custom transparent panel is a child of the MapView, not the root application view. This is why it's able to overlay the MapView content.